# Want to convert 12 hour time string to time object in Node JS/MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, timestamp

I have time Eg: "1:30 pm" as a string and want to convert it into time object.
Can anyone provide a solution for the same in JS or MySQL?

I have tried time_format in MySQL and in JS I have tried following functions:-

- getTime()
- setTime()
- toLocaleTimeString()

Comment: Think you are looking for more or less `TIME(STR_TO_DATE(
      CONCAT(DATE(NOW()) , ' 1:30 pm')
   , '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p' 
 ))` ... See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h3EemacjbkFs9cT4TKGAoX/2)  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string in JavaScript, once this is done you can create a Date() object from the result using [Date.setHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), or you can simple create an object with hours and minutes properties.

```js
const examples = ["01:30 pm", "11:15 pm", "07:30", "5:10 am", "00:30", "14:05 pm"];

function timeStringToDate(timeString) {
    const { hours, minutes } = timeStringToObject(timeString);
    const date = new Date();
    date.setHours(hours, minutes, 0, 0);
    return date;
}

function timeStringToObject(timeString) {
    const components = timeString.match(/(\d+):(\d+)\s?(\w*)/);
    const hours = /pm/i.test(components[3]) && parseInt(components[1]) < 12 ? parseInt(components[1]) + 12 : parseInt(components[1]);
    const minutes = parseInt(components[2]);
    return { hours, minutes };
}

examples.forEach(timeString => console.log({ timeString, timeObject: timeStringToObject(timeString), date: timeStringToDate(timeString)}))
```

To run a query using this function in Node.js would look like so:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "some_user",
    password : 'secret',
    database: "test_db"
});

connection.connect();

const date = timeStringToDate("2:30 pm");

connection.query("SELECT * FROM Events WHERE Date > ?", [ date ],  (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) { 
        console.error("An error occurred: ", error);
    } else {
        console.log("The solution is: ", results);
    }
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953735/9904790 @TerryLennox I have to pass it in a SQL query which doest satisfy the where clause.

Comment: Hi @siddharthosatwal, I've updated to include a MySql query in Node.js. This may help you!